# Error with osmnx while creating graph from xml file

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am trying to build a graph where nodes would be the cities of the Friuli-Venezia Giulia region and the edges the roads connecting them (edge's weight being the road length).
I therefore decided to use data from openstreetmaps, I found a way to download an extract containing all I need (https://download.openstreetmap.fr/extracts/europe/italy/). Then I filtered the data using osmfilter to retain only what I needed

```
osmfilter file.osm --keep-nodes="place=* and population>1000 " --keep-ways="highway=primary =secondary =tertiary" --drop-relations --keep= -o=new.osm
```

So far everything went well (I guess). It is when I am trying to use osmnx to create the graph that an error occurs

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph.graph_from_xml('new.osm', simplify=True)
```

The error is the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'deg2rad'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-75f455d1bcf4> in <module>
----> 1 G = ox.graph.graph_from_xml('new.osm', simplify=True)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/graph.py in graph_from_xml(filepath, bidirectional, simplify, retain_all)
    516 
    517     # create graph using this response JSON
--> 518     G = _create_graph(response_jsons, bidirectional=bidirectional, retain_all=retain_all)
    519 
    520     # simplify the graph topology as the last step

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/graph.py in _create_graph(response_jsons, retain_all, bidirectional)
    585     # add length (great-circle distance between nodes) attribute to each edge
    586     if len(G.edges) > 0:
--> 587         G = distance.add_edge_lengths(G)
    588 
    589     return G

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py in add_edge_lengths(G, precision, edges)
    152 
    153     # calculate great circle distances, round, and fill nulls with zeros
--> 154     dists = great_circle_vec(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3]).round(precision)
    155     dists[np.isnan(dists)] = 0
    156     nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values=dict(zip(uvk, dists)), name="length")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osmnx/distance.py in great_circle_vec(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2, earth_radius)
     58         earth_radius
     59     """
---> 60     y1 = np.deg2rad(lat1)
     61     y2 = np.deg2rad(lat2)
     62     dy = y2 - y1

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable deg2rad method
```

Any idea of what is wrong? I would also be glad if anyone knows a better way to create such graph.

Thank you very much

Comment: Look inside your .OSM file. Are the node coordinates all floating point numeric?

Comment: Hi, I do not know much about xml file and how data is encoded but I guess you are right they are not floating point numeric. Here one line that stand for Trieste
<node id="66502648" lat="45.6496485" lon="13.7772781" version="48" timestamp="2022-09-17T07:45:40Z" changeset="126287747" uid="16531246" user="mk2k22">. I imagine the " " mean that they are strings